# PyTesseract not seeing some single-digit numbers in table

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have this image of a table

[image: image_of_table]

I'm trying to parse it using PyTesseract. I've gotten pretty darn close using this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import pytesseract

og_image = Image.open('og_image.png')
grayscale = ImageOps.grayscale(og_image)
inverted = ImageOps.invert(grayscale.convert('RGB'))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(inverted))
```

This seems to be very accurate, except the single-digit numbers in the second-to-last column are blank. Do I need to do something different to pick up on those numbers?

Comment: Have the same issue rn as well. In my case, if all the numbers are single digit, it works. Not an ideal solution, but if you could remove all the multi-digit numbers and reprocess the image, it may work. (Note: I have no idea why.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tesseract` has several modes of page segmentation, and choosing the right one is necessary to help it getting best result. See [documentation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tesseract/).

Also in this case, you can restrict `tesseract` to a certain character set.

Another thing, `tesseract` is sensitive to the fonts and image size. A simple resizing can change the results greatly. Here I change image size horizontally by factor 2 and vertically to get best result ;)

Combining all the above, you will get:

```
custom_config = r'--psm 6  -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(inverted.resize((1506, 412), Image.ANTIALIAS), config=custom_config))
      
1525 .199 303 82 161 162 7 .241
1464 .290 424 70 139 198 25 .352
1456 .292 425 116 224 224 0 .345
1433 .240 346 81 130 187 15 .275
1390 .273 373 108 217 216 3 .345
1386 .276 383 54 181 154 18 .315
1225 .208 255 68 148 129 1 .242
1218 .238 230 46 128 127 18 .273
1117 .240 268 43 113 1193 1 .308
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about the resizing? For example, trying to run this image https://gist.github.com/gumdropsteve/b598f41f420f7ee3acac641ea603c8fb#gistcomment-3436939 I found cropping out the 0 and resizing it to 100x100 worked, but I'm struggling to figure out a resizing that works for all the numbers at once.Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no rule to find the right size. I understand it is related to the data `tesseract` was trained upon, so optimally your font aspect ratio and character size should be close to those in the training. It is really not very robust. Even if you change vertical size by a single pixel in the above example, you will get some new errors

Comment: From the [tesseract documenation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/FAQ-Old#is-there-a-minimum--maximum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text) it seems that optimal letter vertical size should be around 20-25 pixels.

Comment: Awesome, that worked for me! I had tried a config before but I don't think I set it up correctly.